# How do I select only the "top nodes" in this XPath query?

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

I'm using this XPath query to select elements that do not have input descendants in an Xhtml document:

```
//*[not(descendant-or-self::input | descendant-or-self::textarea | descendant-or-self::select | ancestor::select)]
```

With the following example XHtml document:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="one">
            <input type="text" />
        </div>
        <div id="two">
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>
        <div id="three">
            <div id="four">
                Text
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="five">
            <select>
                <option>One</option>
                <option>Two</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="six">
            <input type="text" />
        </div>
        <div id="seven">
            <div id="eight"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

...And this PHP code:

```
// Populate $html and $query with above

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadXML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query($query);

foreach($nodes as $node)
{
    echo $node->tagName;

    if($node->hasAttribute('id'))
        echo '#' . $node->getAttribute('id');

    echo ' ';
}
```

I get this: `head title div#three div#four div#seven div#eight`

But I want this instead: `head div#three div#seven`

I will be taking the results of the XPath query and removing the elements from DOMDocument. `title div#four div#eight` are children of `head div#three div#seven`, which are already in the result.

Keeping in mind this query will be used on any XHtml document, how would I change my XPath 1.0 query to get the desired results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just repeat the condition for the parent:

```
[not(descendant-or-self::input | descendant-or-self::textarea | descendant-or-self::select | ancestor-or-self::select)
and 
(../descendant-or-self::input | ../descendant-or-self::textarea | ../descendant-or-self::select | ../ancestor-or-self::select)]
```

Comment: This works! It seems that it's enough for the repeated condition to be `and (../descendant::input | ../descendant::textarea | ../descendant::select)`. The `ancestor-or-self::select` part of the first condition ensures the inside of the `select` is left alone. The `../` part, if I understand correctly, selects the "root parent", which is exactly what I wanted, thanks :). I also added a fallback to select the root node, `html`, if there are no field elements.

Comment: I discovered an issue with the query not working when the `xmlns` attribute was present on the `html` element. For what ever reason you can't simply do `$xpath->registerNamespace(NULL, 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml')`... So instead you have to change `NULL` to `'html'` and do `$query = str_replace('::', '::input:', $query)` when the xmlns is present. You can use `$xmlns = $document->lookupNamespaceURI(NULL)` to see if it is present. Wish there was a better way. If there is, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

In this case it appears to be enough to extend your current xpath to additionally say that there should not be a `div` or a `head` in the `ancestor` axis:

```
//*[not(descendant-or-self::input 
      | descendant-or-self::textarea 
      | descendant-or-self::select 
      | ancestor::select
      | ancestor::div
      | ancestor::head)]
```

On the sample xml, this returns just the `head` and `div`s `three` and `seven`, as desired.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work for every XHtml/Html5 document. It's too specific. I can only be specific about the form fields. There are ton block/inline elements that can contain a form field that would have to be listed here. Missing one of them could result in an error (trying to remove a tag who's parent was already removed).